# Get other fields in an Object by using external Id but not SOQL Query

Tags: apex, lightning, soql, salesforcedx

I have a requirement, where I have the external Id of an Object and would like to fetch other field values in the object using only the External ID but not SOQL query.

The reason I don't want to use SOQL is I am getting a list of external Ids and don't want to use SOQL in for loop. 
I can use SOQL outside for loop and iterate but looking for a simple process.

Can something like this be achieved in Apex,

```
Custom_Object__c ob=new Custom_Object__c(External_Id__c='ExternalId');//External Id field
System.debug(ob.Custom_Field__c);
```

Please help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot be done as you suggest.

But if you need to get a list of objects by their External Id, there is no need for SOQL in a loop. Assuming you have a list of external IDs, you can get your objects with just one statement:

```
List<Id> externalIds; // assuming these are passed from somewhere else
List<Custom_Object__c> objs = [SELECT Id, External_Id__c, Custom_Field__c 
                               FROM Custom_Object__c 
                               WHERE External_Id__c IN :externalIds];
```

You probably want to get specific objects from this result, so its usually good to put them into a map:

```
Map<Id, Custom_Object__c> objMap = new Map<Id, Custom_Object__c> ();
for (Custom_Object__c obj : objs) {
    objMap.put (obj.External_Id__c, obj);
}
```

Then you can directly access a specific object as defined by an external Id using

```
Custom_Object__c myObject = objMap.get (myExternalId);
```

and then access the custom field on that:

```
System.debug (myObject.Custom_Field__c);
```

Comment: Florian, what I'm trying to understand is without using SOQL, for any object is there a way to get the object fields in a simpler way. I do always go with the above approach you talked about, but is there any other way that can be used? Trying to understand all possible ways.

Comment: You definitely need some kind of query, you have to tell the system what you need. If you construct a new object from an external Id, you can only set certain properties to be changed by an update, but you cannot query properties other then by SOQL or SOSL.

Comment: Thank You Florian